# Auto wallpaper changer

Tags: samsung, automation, 9.0-pie, wallpaper

I need to auto download wallpaper from internet and set based on a frequency ( daily or hourly ) ?
I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 8 on Android Pie. Is this functionality available in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Casualis:Auto wallpaper change](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ph.url.tangodev.randomwallpaper). It can:

> lets you have an always new wallpaper without lifting a finger: you just have to decide when you want Casualis to activate and you're done!
>
> Features:
>
> - Set a random wallpaper every 1/3/6/12 hours or every 1/3/7 days, at the time you prefer;
> - Choose a wallpaper manually among over 3000 high-resolution images or use your own images;

In the settings, you can select the wallpapers from. Disadvantage: It shows ads.

Or you can try [Wallpapers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wallpaper).

> - Enjoy a collection that keeps on growing. Access images from Google Earth, Google+, and other partners.
> - Double your fun. Show the world one wallpaper on your lock screen, and keep one for yourself on your home screen. (Requires Android™ 7.0, Nougat, and above.)
> - Start each day fresh. Pick your favorite category and you’ll get a new wallpaper image each day.

Disadvantage: Made by Google and not updated since 2018.